# Impossible to add an owner to a Google Site using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I wrote a Google Apps Script in order to make a copy of a Google Site template, and then add a new owner to this copy.
I use the [copySite](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app#copySite%28String,String,String,String,Site%29) function, which is asynchronous as the documentation states :

> The copy is asynchronous, and the copy operation may still be ongoing
>   even though a reference to the site has been returned

After the site has been copied, I want to add a new owner to the site using the [addOwner](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site#addOwner%28String%29) function, just like this :

```
var template = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(TEMPLATE_URL); // Retrieve the template
var copyOfTemplate = SitesApp.copySite(domain, url, googleSiteName, summary, template);
copiedTemplateURL = copyOfTemplate.getUrl();
copyOfTemplate.addOwner(adminMail); // Add the customer as owner of the new site
```

The script runs well (no error), the Google site is created, but the owner is not added, and sometimes, the "getUrl()" function doesn't return anything. I tried to add a delay (Utilities.sleep) of 20 seconds, but it doesn't seem to work, and I think it is a "dirty" solution. 
Can anybody think of a workaround for this case ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a workaround to my issue.

It seems that if the Google site you copy contains many pages, the process time for this copy will be longer and if you try to add an owner **during this time**, it won't work. Moreover, if you use the [getOwners()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site#getOwners%28%29) function after adding an owner(during the copy time), it will return you the correct owners. However, when the site is entirely copied, the owner you added is not mentioned in the sharing settings and therefore can not access the copy of your site template.

The idea is to wait for the copy to be completed, by counting the number of descendant pages that are returned by the [getAllDescendants()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site#getAllDescendants%28%29) function on the copied template, and compare it to the number returned by the same function on your original template. Then, you can safely add a new owner.

```
var timer = 1000;
var template = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/domain.ext/yourtemplate"); // Retrieve the template
var copyOfTemplate = SitesApp.copySite(domain, url, googleSiteName, summary, template);
var descendants = copyOfTemplate.getAllDescendants().length;
var numberOfPages = template.getAllDescendants().length;

while(descendants < numberOfPages || descendants === null) {
  Utilities.sleep(timer);
  timer = timer + 5000; // sort of "additionnal backoff"
  descendants = copyOfTemplate.getAllDescendants().length;
}
//At this point the copy should be completed
copyOfTemplate.addOwner("yourNewOwner@domain.ext"); // Add the customer as owner of the new site
```

My template contains 41 descendant pages, it takes approximately 35 seconds to copy it properly.